# Почему Integer кеширование не работает при арифметических операциях?

Tags: java

Всем привет. Прохожу тест. Вот, столкнулся с непонятностью. Вопрос:

> Что будет выведено на экран?

```
Integer a = 128; 
Integer b = 128; 
Integer c = -128; 
Integer d = -128; 
System.out.println(a == b); 
System.out.println(c == d);
```

Я ответил `false, false`. Неправильно. Обьяснение:

> Для повышения эффективности boxing conversion (преобразования значения примитивного типа в объект соответствующего класса-оболочки) для небольших по модулю целочисленных значений используются заранее созданные объекты классов Integer (-128 .. 127), Byte (-128 .. 127), Short (-128 .. 127), Character (0 .. 127). Эти наборы обычно называют кэш (напр., integer cache) или пул (напр., integer pool).
>   Поэтому c == d даёт true.
>   Для остальных значений во время boxing conversion каждый раз создаётся новый объект. Поэтому a == b даёт false.

И еще один вопрос:

```
Integer ii = 1000;
Integer jj = 2000;
System.out.print((ii * 2 == jj) ? "yes " : "no "); 
System.out.print((jj / 2 == ii) ? "yes " : "no "); 
System.out.print((ii * 2 == jj) ^ (jj / 2 == ii) ? "yes " : "no ");
```

Я ответил, что выведется `no no no`. Неверно. Обьяснение:

> При выполнении любых арифметических операций (умножение, деление, ...) объекты классов-оболочек (Integer) автоматически разворачиваются в значения примитивного типа (int). Результатом любой арифметической операции также будет значение примитивного типа.
>   Если с помощью == сравниваются значение примитвного типа и объект-оболочка, то объект автоматически разворачивается, и происходит сравнение двух примитивов.
>   Результатом операции ^ (исключающее ИЛИ) будет false, так как оба операнда true.

**Почему во втором вопросе не указано кеширование от -128 до 127?**
Спасибо.

Comment: А зачем? Там ведь нет значений от -128 до 127.

Comment: Ответ уже есть в вопросе. Прочитайте объяснения внимательно. Оба объяснения.

Comment: @D-side, при арифметической операции оболочка разворачивается в примитив. А у него уже нет кеширования, так?)

Comment: Совершенно верно! То есть, нельзя точно сказать, что оболочки аргументов разворачиваются (хотя внутри наверняка), но результат, в любом случае, примитивный.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Если с помощью == сравниваются значение примитвного типа и объект-оболочка, то объект автоматически разворачивается, и происходит сравнение двух примитивов.

Вы упустили этот момент. Кеш для значений -128 - 127 создается для объектов (то есть Integer, для int все будет ок). А теперь:

> При выполнении любых арифметических операций (умножение, деление, ...) объекты классов-оболочек (Integer) автоматически разворачиваются в значения примитивного типа

То есть при выполнении умножения на 2, наш Integer автоматически превратился в обычный int. И дальше мы уже сравниваем не дв объекта, а примитив с объектом.

А дальше снова смотрим на первую цитату, при сравнении с примитивом, объект тоже превращается  в примитив (Integer -> int)

Comment: Понял, спасибо! Интересно тогда, а если например сложить два `Integer` то они тоже оба развернутся в примитив?)

Comment: Да, развернуться ) `new Integer(1000) + new Integer(1000) == new Integer(2000); // true`. Вообще честно говоря, не знаю зачем на многих тестах по Java об этом спрашивают, но все же понимание, что такое Boxing, unboxing, что такое сслыка, а что такое примитив это развивает )

Comment: спасибо огромное!

Answer (score 1):

Небольшое уточнение по первой части вопроса: верхнюю границу кэша для конкретно класса `Integer` можно увеличить, указав ее в параметре JVM `java.lang.Integer.IntegerCache.high`.
Таким образом `a == b` может оказаться `true`.

А вот уменьшить нельзя, `c == d` будет `true` всегда.

Подробнее детали реализации боксинга всегда можно подсмотреть в коде метода `valueOf()` соответствующего класса (кроме `String` – там работает [интернирование](https://itsobes.ru/JavaSobes/32.html)). Еще пару примеров можно посмотреть [здесь](https://itsobes.ru/JavaSobes/31.html).